I need help understanding something from How to solve it book.
From the How to Solve It book (full page), here with some extra line breaks and emphasized passages for the questions below:

J. E. Littlewood gives two amusing examples of assumptions that can easily be made unconsciously and misleadingly.
First, he remarks that the description of the coordinate axes ("Ox and Oy as in 2 dimensions, Oz vertical") in Lamb's book, Mechanics is incorrect for him, since he always worked in an armchair with his feet up!
Then, after asking how his reader would present the picture of a closed curve lying all on one side of its tangent, he states that there are four main schools (to the left or right of a vertical tangent, or above or below a horizontal one) and that by lecturing without a figure, presuming that the curve was to the right of its vertical tangent, he had unwittingly made nonsense for the other three schools.

My questions:

I need clarification for the phrase "armchair with his feet up" what this has to do with the coordinate system?

Then here I need breakdown and explanation for "closed curve lying all on one side of its tangent".

Also what this four schools for and how can the represented graphically?



I believe the armchair anecdote refers to the notion that the sense of which coordinate axis is best described as "vertical" can be different for someone reclining in an armchair (with a book or notepad held upright? on the lap?), vs someone sitting at a desk, vs someone standing at a blackboard.
The "four schools [of thought]" about visualizing "a closed curve lying all on one side of its tangent" are as follows:

(Of course, other schools may envision slanted tangents.)
A lecturer using School $1$'s mental picture ---and likely describing elements of the figure in terms of "left", "right", "up", "down", etc--- will tend to confuse listeners who have the other pictures in their minds. So, a lecturer should take care to provide ample clues about how their own visualizations are organized. (Or, y'know ... provide an image.)
